# verify_oauth2_token uses object as function

Tags: python, google-authentication

I was doing google auth with use of backend from there:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

It seems a bit outdated and the most strange thing is that there is a line:

```
idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), CLIENT_ID)
```

and in implementation you can see that in nested function calls, same request object lands there:

```
def _fetch_certs(request, certs_url):
"""Fetches certificates.

Google-style cerificate endpoints return JSON in the format of
``{'key id': 'x509 certificate'}``.

Args:
    request (google.auth.transport.Request): The object used to make
        HTTP requests.
    certs_url (str): The certificate endpoint URL.

Returns:
    Mapping[str, str]: A mapping of public key ID to x.509 certificate
        data.
"""
response = request(certs_url, method='GET')
```

request is an object, even documentation claims so and it uses it as function. The error I get is:

> TypeError: 'Request' object is not callable

What should be changed there?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you are calling the wrong python requests lib.

If you need to differentiate between the 2 available requests lib.

```
from google.auth.transport import requests as google_auth_request
import requests

req = google_auth_request.Request()

idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, req, CLIENT_ID)
```

See: https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.id_token.html